# Popup para responder a própria questão

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

A mensagem que aparece quando clica em responder a sua própria questão é:

> Are you sure you want to answer your own question?
>
> ```
> If you're responding to answers left on your question, enter comments under each answer.
>
> If you need to add details to your question, use the edit link under your question
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Você tem certeza que você quer responder sua própria pergunta?
>
> > ```
> > Se você está respondendo(ou replicando) uma resposta deixada em sua pergunta,
> > insira comentários abaixo de cada resposta
> >
> > Se você precisa adicionar mais detalhes a sua pergunta, 
> > use o link editar abaixo de sua pergunta
> > ```